# GlassFish Server HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Tags: java, netbeans, web-applications, glassfish, server

Product Version = NetBeans IDE 8.1 
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1
I have a very simple web application created with Netbeans 7.0.1 which includes only a RESTful Webservice.
Here my jsp file

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>TEST !</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I deploy the project to my locally installed Glassfish and run the projet named (MyRest) in get http://http://localhost:8080/MyRest in my browser everything is executed as expected what means that I can see my "TEST !" message.

Now changing to NetBeans I open in my project the node "RESTful Web Services", make a right-click on any HTTP method and choose "Test Resource Uri" from the context menu. After that a warning dialog shows up with the following message:

```
Unable to open resource url:
http://localhost:8080/MyRest/webresources/service/getJsonWithParam
Make sure the project has been deployed successfully, and the server is
running.
```

I even tried to change the url manually then I get

```
HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
type Status report

messageNot Found

descriptionThe requested resource is not available.


GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Did you create this in NB 7.0.1, then open it later with NB 8.1? Did it work in NB 7.0.1, or has it always failed like this?

Comment: No i created this in NB 8.1

Comment: When you test it **without** netbeans your glasfish server runs. Now before you start Netbeans have you shutdown Glasfish? If Not Netbeans uses the next port wich is **8081** ! Have you test this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have typed http:// two times! Did you check this as well?

Comment: He didn't type that, it's the reason why he's having the problem